# Web2py and/or Cappuccino (Objective-J) for CPU intensive tasks

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py, cappuccino

I started a CPU-intensive project in web2py which at some point needs a dynamic GUI interface. Due to the intensive nature of the processing, I am unsure whether embedding this python code (in web2py views) would be price-sensitive as deployed to GAE (GoogleAppEngine) with its server-side processing, at least compared to using another framework, etc. Correct me if I am misinterpreting how the code will be processed or if there is an easy way around this (a separate or integral client-side processing implementation, if possible))

Due to the lack of information in cross-referencing Web2py with Cappuccino, I assume combining their mechanisms would be an untenable prospect.

Comment: very similar to this which you already asked. you need to become more familiar with web development i think. yout questions are too broad. http://stackoverflow.com/q/31107712/2213940

Comment: Sorry, this is a time-sensitive issue. A broad question, in this case, only exists because there was a lack of information or it was not readily available.

Comment: @Zig Mandel Also, learning by doing is the best way to learn without wasting time. I am only 1 week in to web development, but am trying to determine the best framework to start in before wasting time.

Comment: if you wantxtocdo clientside processing, writting it directly with javascript wull give you the most power and flexibility.

Comment: @Zig Mandel To be sure, if necessary to process in python, it would be best to create a desktop interface that does the python processing (as would not be client-side in terms of server processing), and just update the database with javascript?

Comment: if you make a deaktop python app theres no need for javascript.

Comment: Note to everyone: currently nothing on Cappuccino on this side yet, so this dialogue will continue, if at all, at the link posted in Zig's first comment. Thanks

Comment: although, in response to "if you make a deaktop python app theres no need for javascript," I was referring to the javascript in the web app the desktop app is connecting to.